# Changing stroke attribute on a single RaphaelJS object, when there are multiple objects on the page

Tags: onclick, raphael

I've got a whole bunch of rects on my canvas.

I'd like to change the stroke on whatever rect the user clicks, as well as running some other javascript.  My simplified code is below.

```
var canvas = Raphael("test");
var st = canvas.set();

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var act = canvas.rect(///edited for brevity////).attr({"stroke":"none"});
   st.push(act)

   act.node.onclick = function() {
      st.attr({stroke: "none"});
      act.attr({stroke: "yellow"});
   }   
}
```

Right now, no matter what rect I click on, it's only changing the stroke on the last rect drawn.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a Raphaël problem but rather lack of closure understanding. Easily could be fixed by self invoking function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var act = canvas.rect(///edited for brevity////).attr({"stroke":"none"});
    st.push(act)


    (function (act) {
       act.node.onclick = function() {
           st.attr({stroke: "none"});
           act.attr({stroke: "yellow"});
       }
    })(act);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it for me.

Answer (score 0):

//Try and then embellish

```
st[i].click(function (e) 
{ 
    this.attr({stroke: "yellow"});
```

}